# Django upload many images and save to model

Tags: python, django

I have seen similar questions, but they are old. I wonder if there is a new better approach to this process.

I have a form that uploads many images at once. ¿How do I process them with django and create one model object per uploaded image?

I have a model with an Image field:

```
class XModel(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(...)
```

Can I use a `ModelForm`? Should I use a normal `forms.Form` and a `MemoryUploadedFile`?

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is how I did it. Maybe there is a better way but anyway:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        files = request.FILES.getlist('images')
        for x in files:
            XModel.objects.create(image=x)
        return HttpResponse('Yeii')
```